# Cálculo de data e tag onblur

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando uma tela para adicionar pedidos. Quando eu escolho a data da venda, eu gostaria que, automaticamente, ele calculasse a data de vencimento e trocasse o valor do campo de vencimento (que sempre é 180 dias após a data da compra).

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>&nbsp;Valor do Pedido : </td>
        <td align='left'><input style="width: 115px;" id="VALOR_PEDIDO" required value="" name="VALOR_PEDIDO" type='text' maxlength='100' tabindex='5' size='30'/></td>
        <td align='left'>&nbsp;Data da venda : </td>
        <td align='left'><input style="width: 115px;" id="DATA_VENDA" required value="" name="DATA_VENDA" type="us-date0" OnKeyUp="mascara_data(this.value)" type='text' maxlength='10' tabindex='5' size='30'/></td>
        <td align='left'>&nbsp;Data de vencimento EBS : </td>
        <td align='left'><input style="width: 115px;" id="DATA_VENC_EBS" required value="" name="DATA_VENC_EBS" type="us-date0" OnKeyUp="mascara_data(this.value)" type='text' maxlength='10' tabindex='5' size='30'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Aí estão os campos, mas não tenho a menor ideia de como resolver esse problema. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Caso isso seja de alguma importância, ambos os campos de data abrem um calendário, mas não restringem o usuário de escrever no campo.

```js
                        var month = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;
                        var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
                        $('input[type=us-date0]').w2field('date', {format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', placeholder: 'dd/mm/aaaa'});
```

Comment: Porque não cria uma função JavaScript e invoca-a no evento `onblur` do elemento `DATA_VENDA`?

Comment: Infelizmente eu tentei mas por alguma razão o onblur não funcionou, então gostaria de um exemplo

Comment: O que faz a função `mascara_data`? Podes coloca-la na pergunta?

Comment: Adicionado a pergunta, tinha me esquecido de adicionar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente a data digitada em DATA_VENDA será no padrão brasileiro (dia/mes/ano), e não no americano (mes/dia/ano). Logo, você vai precisar tratar este valor antes de fornecê-lo para a variável "dataVenda" (acredito que sua função de máscara já faça este tratamento).

O seguinte script vai associar a função novaData ao evento onblur do input DATA_VENDA:

```
document.getElementById('DATA_VENDA').onblur = novaData();

function novaData(){

    var dataVenda = new Date( document.getElementById('DATA_VENDA').value );

    var vencEbs= new Date(new Date(dataVenda).setMonth(dataVenda.getMonth()+6));

    var dia = vencEbs.getDate()    
    var mes = vencEbs.getMonth()+1; //janeiro é 0
    var ano = vencEbs.getFullYear(); 

  document.getElementById('DATA_VENC_EBS').value = dia+' /'+mes+' /'+ano;

}
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de definir o `hoje`, acho que no lugar podia ser `dataVenda`, não?

Comment: Isso mesmo, refatorei e acabei esquecendo o nome anterior da variável.

Comment: Sua solução é boa, mas infelizmente não funciona, quando abro a tela, no campo `DADA_VENC_EBS` aparece da seguinte maneira **NaN /NaN /NaN**

Comment: Então deve haver algum erro quando as variaveis dataVenda e vencEbs são criadas. Você pode tentar adicionar "console.log(variavel);" logo abaixo para ver o que está acontecendo. Se você puder montar um jsfiddle com o formulário fica mais fácil.

Comment: OK, só da uma olhada no post novamente, eu coloquei junto o `input` de data, caso ajude em alguma coisa. Estou testando aqui, procurando os erros.